# Delete items from ListView with a custom adapter

Tags: android

I use BaseAdapter to display items on a ListView. i add PopupMenu that allows the user to delete row
I managed to removing item by using `NameObjects.remove(position);`  but i have a problem with updating the listView automatically how i can do it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use  `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: thank you anyway ,I tried with notifyDataSetChanged but i get anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your adapter notifyDataSetChanged (or invalidated) when you remove or change something in your data.

Also using a BaseAdapter to manager an arraylist ? why not use an ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: I tried with notifyDataSetChanged  but i get nothing :)